# show jquery result in a dynamic div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I can show the results of an ajax request in a div created by HTML but I cannot do the same when the div is generated by PHP. Can anyone shed some light???

```
$('#result'+id).html(result);

$show_results .='<div id="result'.$id.'">
//I want to show my result here..
</div>';

echo $show_results;
```

This is just a part of the code..I have already sent the value to database through ajax along with it's id.

Comment: There's something odd with your question. jQuery is for client side only and PHP is server side only. In your question, they seem mixed to me. Can you post the server side, then the resulting client side code?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your $.ajax request the dataType parameter with 'html' as value. For example:

```
.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'html'
............. rest of your code
```

Jquery usually tries to guess the type of the returned content from the request checking the MIME Type.

Comment: Can you post the response of your request and what you expected it to be?

Comment: It is showing the results altogether on the top of the page..and not identifying the div that I mentioned already..It is actually a commenting system designed to post comments under respective post like facebook.. That's why I have given an id.. which is post_id.. all comments are showing on top of the page and not within the div..I doubt that jquery understands a dynamic div generated by php. am i right?

Comment: Can you put it online somewhere so I can see what it's happening? You cant add a div from php to DOM, but you can create it dynamically with  jQuery.

Comment: My entire post div is within php..And within each post div there lies a comment div..So I don't think I can write post div in php and comment div in jquery..How can I merge them together.? I am just working on my school project..I don't have a server to put it online

Comment: If I get this right, this might be a solution. Replace `$('#result'+id).html(result);` with `$('#results').append(result);`, and where you want them to display on your page add in html `<div id="resuts"></div` .

Comment: how? may u give an example?

Comment: Updated my answer, pressed enter as a reflex.

Comment: I cant do more without seeing the whole code sorry, try putting your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ .

Answer (score 0):

this php code works for me:

```
<?php
  $id = 1;
  $show_results .='<div id="result'.$id.'">
  //I want to show my result here..
  </div>';
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<script>
    var id = 1;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#result'+id).html("42");

    });
</script>

<body>
<? echo $show_results; ?>
</body>
</html>
```